# Use Trino in an Istio Service Mesh, nodes cannot reach each other over pod ip

Tags: kubernetes, istio, trino

I have the [Trino helm chart](https://trino.io/docs/current/installation/kubernetes.html) in a kubernetes namespace with labels `istio-injection=enabled`. Trino's clustering is configured so that workers announce themselves to the coordinator. The coordinator then arranges that all nodes in the cluster receive all the pod ip's of all other nodes.

Istio is a Service Mesh, not a pod mesh, and its proxy sidecar does not support traffic directly to the pod ip.

So as such, the Trino coordinator can not open connections with the workers, and workers can only talk to the coordinator through its service fqdn (`trino.trino.svc.cluster.local` in my case).

Is there a solution to make the coordinator talk to the workers and get this cluster up an running without turning of all security (i.e. take it outside of the service mesh)?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, the solution was as follows:

1. Create the Headless-service

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: trino-headless-coordinator
  namespace: trino
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
    - name: tcp-trino
      port: 8080
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: trino
    component: coordinator
  type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: trino-headless-worker
  namespace: trino
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
    - name: tcp-trino
      port: 8080
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: trino
    component: worker
  type: ClusterIP
```

2. Restart the pod

```bash
kubectl rollout restart -n trino deployment trino-coordinator
kubectl rollout restart -n trino deployment trino-worker
```

I don't know why restarting the Pod is necessary but this stopped the following 502 error

```
[2023-10-04T00:56:27.076Z] "GET /v1/info/state HTTP/1.1" 502 - direct_response - "-" 0 0 0 - "-" "-" "2567ad09-dff9-484c-907d-d6b4076c341f" "[2406:da14:dc0:6300:9ea4::b]:8080" "-" - - [2406:da14:dc0:6300:9ea4::b]:8080 [2406:da14:dc0:6301:e0a4::8]:45174 - block_all
...
```

I hope this will help someone solve similar issues.

Comment: Interesting. Does this mean that you do not need use the name 'ip' for the headless service, and you can skip the `node.internal-address-source=IP_ENCODED_AS_HOSTNAME` setting?

Comment: thank you for your reply! Yes, I could skip the `node.internal-address-source=IP_ENCODED_AS_HOSTNAME ` setting

Answer (score 0):

Its been a rabbit hole, but I found hacky way which does make the nodes find each other.

Trino borrows code from Airlift, notably [this part](https://github.com/airlift/airlift/blob/e1e12774a64406f3a4e67ca5ceda7be41862f7d6/node/src/main/java/io/airlift/node/NodeConfig.java). It has the configuration parameter `node.internal-address-source` which is an enum with possible values:

```java
public enum AddressSource
    {
        HOSTNAME,
        FQDN,
        IP,
        IP_ENCODED_AS_HOSTNAME
    }
```

So, in the values.yaml with which you install the helm chart, add these lines:

```yaml
additionalConfigProperties:
  - node.internal-address-source=IP_ENCODED_AS_HOSTNAME
```

Now, this is not enough yet, but you may see where this is going. The logs of the workers now show lines like these:

```
2023-03-16T14:40:01.342Z        WARN    http-client-node-manager-32     io.trino.metadata.RemoteNodeState        Error fetching node state from http://10-42-1-186.ip:8080/v1/info/state returned status 503
```

I did not find a way to configure a different hostname then `ip` in that address. So, if the mountain won't come to ..., instead of renaming ip to what I want, I renamed what I have to ip. Add the following headless service to your Trino installation.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: trino
  name: ip
  namespace: trino
spec:
  clusterIP: None # this makes it headless.
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 8080
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: http
  selector:
    app: trino
  type: ClusterIP
```

name that file `trino-headless.yaml` and apply it with `kubectl -n trino apply -f trino-headless.yaml`.

That it. Now your workers and coordinator are all reachable under A-B-C-D.ip where A-B-C-D is set by IP_ENCODED_AS_HOSTNAME .

I think this lets you use Trino entirely inside a service mesh.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this!

However, this does not work in IPv6-only environment. Here is the log.


```log
2023-10-11T07:01:07.041Z    WARN    http-client-node-manager-52    io.trino.metadata.RemoteNodeState    Error fetching node state from http://x2406-da14-dc0-6301-8458--9.ip:8080/v1/info/state
 returned status 502
```


(The IP is weird... `x` is prepended... ) Would you happen to have any ideas to solve this...?

Comment: I wrote a simple solution that worked in my IPv6 environment in https://stackoverflow.com/a/77313811/5986291